# Scrollbar on chrome and edge but not on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, scroll

I developed my website in chrome and now im trying to get it to work in every browser, I a custom scrollbar which didn't show up on internet explorer at all, which I can understand, but it doesn't show any scrollbar at all, even though scrolling is enabled in all other browsers.
This question is kind of a shot in the dark, because ive checked through most of my css and can't figure out at all what is causing it. The most likely scenario in my head is that it has something to do with this piece of css code;

```
.fixed_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

    .fixed_header tbody {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .fixed_header thead tr {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .fixed_header thead {
        color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

as this is the class for the div that the problem originates from. My  hope is that someone knows the problem and has a potential solution for it.

Comment: I don't see you using browser specific css attributes. `-ms` for Microsoft explorer. You can add `-ms-overflow-style:auto` see if that works for you.

Comment: A good way to get this question answered would be to put the HTML and CSS into jsfiddle (or a similar site) and provide a link to that.